# expo image picker permissions on android

Tags: react-native

I'm encountering a problem with Expo Image Picker on Android it open the albums even i dont ask for  permissions.
and when i ask for permissions it show me the same albums without permissions the problem is they dont show me all albums i have this is my code

```
const addimage = async () => {

    const {status}= await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync()
    if(status !== 'granted'){
      alert('permission not granted')
      return
    }

    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
      
    
    });

    if (!result.canceled) {
      const image = { uri: result.uri, name: result.uri.split('/').pop(), type: "image/jpeg" }
      const FromData = new FormData();
      FromData.append('image', image)
      const obj = { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } }

      const newassets = { ...assets.find(item => item._id === props.data._id), image: [...assets.find(item => item._id === props.data._id).image, image.name] }
      dispatch(updateAsset1({ assets: newassets }))
      await axios.post(`http://141.226.241.38:3001/assets/uplaod/${props.data._id}`, FromData, obj)
    }
  
  }
```

this is my app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-image-picker",
        {
          "photosPermission": "The app accesses your photos to let you share them with your friends."
        }
      ]
    ],
```

ty for help

i update Expo and Library Updates
delete node modules and reinstall